# Number of ways to arrange $i$ distinct objects into tuples, with each listed at least once

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $i<m$.
Suppose you have $i$ distinct objects. You need to arrange them into tuples $(x_1,\dotsc, x_m)$, where repetition is allowed, order matters, and each of the $i$ objects is listed at least once.

**Question:**
What is the numbre of ways $a_{i,m}$ to arrange $i$ distinct objects such that, order matters, repetitions are allowed, and each of the $i$ objects are listed at least once?

**My thoughts:**
I believe this should be $a_{i,m} = i^m-c_{i,m}$ for some number $c_{i,m}$. For example, for $m=4$ and $i=2$, we have $1112, 1121, 1211, 2111, 1122, 1221, 2211, 1212, 2121, 2112, 2221, 2122, 2212, 1222$ i.e. $14$, which is $2^4-2$, so $c_{2,2}=2$, provided I have not miscounted any possibilities.

An argument for this case, without explicitly listing all possibilities and counting them by hand, might look like the following. First, we recall number of $m=4$ tuples with $2$ objects without any other restrictions is
$$2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2=2^4=16.$$
In our specialized case, three slots may have $2$ choices and one slot is forced to be fixed by one choice, so that both $i=2$ elements are accounted for. Unfortunately, here is where my combinatorics is too rusty to formulate this into a simple product formula. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I believe $a_{3, 4}=3^4-45=81-45=36$, and $a_{4, 4}=4^4-232=256-232=24=4!$. I obtained these by backing out $c_{i,m}$ from related formulas.

I apologies in advance if this is well known, I could not find it in my google searches without digging through a lot of combinatorics (which I will do now while waiting for any responses, in hopes to answer this myself).

Comment: Well, since $a_{i,m}$ is clearly less than $i^m$, the form you propose  is certain (but I don't see how it adds much).   As a suggestion, Inclusion-Exclusion lets you compute $a_{i.m}$ in many cases.  For instance, the case $a_{2,4}$ is easily seen to be $2^4-2$ since the only "bad" strings are $1111$ and $2222$.  In general, it will be harder to enumerate the bad strings.

Comment: May be worth noting, $a_{m,m}=m!$ for all $m$, as follows directly from the definition.

Comment: Is this https://oeis.org/A131689 ?

Comment: @lulu Using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle, I obtain, $$a_{i,m}=i^m-i(i-1)^m+i(i-1)(i-2)^{m-1}+\dotsc+(-1)^i(i-1)(i-2)\cdot \dotsc \cdot 3\cdot 2^{m-(i-3)}+(-1)^{i+1} i$$, which has matched all the cases I checked, provided I made no mistakes in my computations. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.